# ERR_CONNECTION_RESET Azure CDN Custom Domain HTTPS

Tags: azure, azure-cdn, custom-domain

Hope someone can assist me in correcting this. I am on the last step to enable my CDN endpoint with a custom domain. currently the static website on storage works correctly the following ways.

1 - Storage Account endpoint
2 - Azure CDN xxxxxx.azureedge.net

CNAME is created and correctly configured and validated in azure for my cdn.customdomain.com but when I try to connect to it I get a ERR_CONNECTION_RESET when using a browser or 404 using curl. Any advice anyone can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could verify the followings:

- Configuration. Make sure you select the `Custom origin` as the `origin type` and static website URI as the `origin hostname`.
- Networking related. ISP blocks some websites. Firewall blocks specific websites. Internet connection is disabled or interrupted. Refer to [this](https://whatsabyte.com/windows/err_connection_reset/).
- Browser error like Chrome. Clear your browser's cache and all locally stored data including cookies or try to use another browser. Refer to [this](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/26561/what-can-cause-a-connection-reset-when-site-is-visited-with-firefox).

Moreover, you could verify this via accessing the `cdn.customdomain.com` in an Azure VM, which is a different environment from the on-premise network.

Comment: If you have any question or update, please let me know.

Comment: What should I put on the Origin Host Header? Thanks a lot for your time

Comment: Usually, the same as the `origin hostname`. In this case, it should also be a static website URI. Such as `yourstoragename.xxx.web.core.windows.net`

Comment: Thanks for the help, you mentioning testing on a VM pointed me in the right direction, the problem was related to a static entry in private DNS server that redirected to an internal IP address. Removing that and allowing public dns to catch up fixed everything.