# Azure website returns ERR_CONNECTION_RESET error after adding custom domain and SSL Certificate

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, ssl-certificate, azure-custom-domain

The URL of my original web app works fine, but I want to use a custom domain, so I apply for Azure SSL Certificate, Key Vault, custom domain. After setting, execute the web page on Edge, Chrome, and the error in the following picture is displayed. How can I debug
Please let me know if you need more information.

[image]

Comment: Please refer [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55056270)

Comment: Thank you, I verified the 3 steps in your link and the browser still shows an error. I use the nslookup command to look through my computer and it shows the public IP of the web app (the IP is correct).  Also, I execute curl command from kudu with CMD and it shows 302 Redirect.